# Using MathPlayer on Linux without Internet Explorer 

Tags: linux, text-to-speech, speech

There is a plugin for Internet Explorer called MathPlayer which is a text-to-speech plug-in for mathematical expressions. It can read mathematical expressions aloud.

However, I'm not using Internet Explorer, since I'm on Linux. Is it possible to use [MathPlayer](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathplayer/) without Internet Explorer?

Or perhaps if that's out, is there comparable software that would run on Linux that would do the same thing?

Comment: Also, should questions like this be posted in http://math.stackexchange.com/ instead of superuser?

Comment: Nope, as this isn't a question about math itself, so I'd say this is the best place for it (since it's about computer software). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple quick Google searches reveal that there is no direct equivalent for Firefox and Chrome (or the alternatives are *really difficult* to find).

Apparently, `winetricks` is able to install IE for you - just install `wine` and `winetricks`, and then run `winetricks ie8`. It downloads the installer automatically, but you have to click through all the annoying dialogs.

Then, download the MathPlayer installer and run it via `wine MathPlayer2.2setup.exe`.

I ran all of the above while typing out this post - everything installs well, but IE8 doesn't run (I get page faults when directing it to http://www.google.com). Maybe you'll have better luck.

---

The only other real option is to dual-boot or run Windows in a VM (I don't really know if ReactOS will run IE8 at this point) to use MathPlayer.

Comment: In that case, is there any other software that can convert mathematical symbols to speech, or at least convert it to text that can be read by a text-to-speech engine?

Comment: @AndersonGreen There's some work going on converting MathML to plain text, which can be fed into a speech engine like `espeak` (it shouldn't be difficult to write, considering MathML is plain XML) - MathML is large and math is complex, however, and its unlikely that anybody has created a converter which produces truly human readable output. Or so intuition tells me after searching a bit and finding nothing.